# Beginner question C++ - How to initialize variables in static object?

Tags: c++, class, object, static, initialization

The following code does not work, so how do I initialize variables/constants?
Is there a way to choose which variable to set for example?

```
class Counter{
  protected:
    int i = 0;

  public:
    int Count(){
        i++;
        return i;
    }

    int num1,num2;            // <--I want to set these numbers
}

int main(){
    static Counter count1 = {10,20};

}
```

I simply want the numbers to be set.
It does work when there is no Private or Protected part in the class though.

Comment: The idea was to not use constructor, as an object stored in file, should be able to have numbers set, and methods assoiated with them, I thought anyway

Comment: "_as an object stored in file, should be able to have numbers set, and methods assoiated with them_": What do you mean with that? What is the problem with using a constructor? Why do you think `static` should make any difference in whether/how constructors are used?

Comment: Well, a constructor is a function that is run in order to set the data in the memory locations of the object. So that is a uneccesary step in this case. When using constructor like you suggest, the data is stored along machine instructions. I would think that a constructor is mainly used when at run time new objects are created. Compiler explorer https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @WhyNot If your goal is to have the values set at compile-time instead of at run-time, then the correct solution is to still use a constructor, but mark it `constexpr` and to add `constinit` on the declaration of `count1` (or even `constexpr` if you don't intent to ever modify `count1`). However, even if you don't add the qualifiers, the compiler is still likely to optimize away the runtime evaluation. The qualifiers just assure that it happens regardless of how well the compiler optimizes.

Comment: @WhyNot constructor runs regardless of whether you've defined your own, or not. If you haven't created your constructor, the default, compiler-defined constructor will run whenever you create an object (doesn't matter if it's static, made on stack, global, created with new, created as a subobject of another object).

The only way you can prevent constructors is to delete them (declare a constructor, and write =delete; after its declaration) or declaring them private. However, this will prevent any construction of an object of your class.

Answer (score 1):

You write a constructor or use aggregate initialization like always. Your class contains a `protected` member, so you cannot use aggregate initialization, and have to write a constructor.

```cpp
class Counter {
// ...
public:
    int num1;
    int num2;
    
    // constructor defined using a member initializer list
    // and an empty constructor body at the end
    Counter(int a, int b) : num1{a}, num2{b} {}
};

int main(){
    static Counter count1 = {10,20};
}
```

`static` doesn't change anything about this. `static` is a property of variables, which changes their storage location. I.e. `count1` will be stored in a *static memory section* instead of on the stack.

*See also: [Static local variables on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables)*

Comment: Well, the whole point of doing it like I tried is to not use contructor.

Comment: @WhyNot you could do it without a constructor, but only if all members of your class are `public`. If so, you can use [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).